# Show which program / task uses the camera (in background)

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, security, camera, background-data, cyanogenmod

On my Samsung Galaxy S2 I9100 with CM11, I always hear a very subtle click of the autofocus whenever the camera app is loaded. Since some weeks, I heard that sound randomly, especially after every restart and reconnect with WiFi. This somehow scares me and looks a bit like my phone is supervised.
Is there a possibility on android (with / without root access) to find out which task uses the camera?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Permissions app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FireFart.Permissions2), and look the the apps under `take pictures and videos`.

Comment: thanks, lots of apps there. I was looking for something like a task manager which shows the active task that just accessed camera functions, or a method to restrict camera access and show which tasks are asking for it. I have cerberus and wheresmydroid installed and could imagine them to stalk after my pictures, or potentially a virus.

Comment: @Axel Are there any pictures being taken?

Comment: The camera is definitely being accessed since I see the camera lens moving every once in a while (once every 30 mins up to once every 15secs),and due to a hardware imprecision the lens touches the glass of the camera, which results in a very distinct click sound. Pictures don't show up in the gallery, but apps like Cerberus can do that easily without leaving any hint besides on my phone the click sound.

Answer (score 0):

[XPrivacy](https://github.com/M66B/XPrivacy) seems to be the tool of choice for these issues, although a bit tough to get through all the settings. Could not find the spying app yet, but will keep this post updated.